# How to make an array from the outputs of an foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, ode

I need to put all the foreach's output (p.X[0] for example) in an array to complete the calculation process and solve the ordinary differential stiff Equations, because the p.x[0] changes with time and I need to have an array that keep them all.
I know the best way to put some data in an array is "for loop", but when you used Microsoft Oslo library, you have to write these code in this way according to the Oslo user guide.
if you know another way for solving these ode equations that can help me with the output, I really appreciate that!
thanks for your help.
here is my codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Research.Oslo;

namespace odestiff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //kinetic constant
           double ka = 200; double ki = 200; double kp = 258.3; double ktrm = 0.0072;
           double ktrh = 0.12; double ktrb = 0.00004; double kd = 0.00001;

            //initial value
            //Ti0 = 1e-5; Al0 = 1e-4;
            //Mo0 = 2; H20 = 1e-2; C0 = 0; M00 = 0; M10 = 0; M20 = 0;
            //L00 = 0; L10 = 0; L20 = 0;

            var sol = Microsoft.Research.Oslo.Ode.GearBDF(
           0,
           new Vector(0.00001, 0.0001, 2, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            (t, x) => new Vector(
            -ka * x[0] * x[1],
            -ka * x[0] * x[1],
            -ktrh * x[2] * x[5],
            -x[3] * x[5] * (kp + ktrm) - ki * x[3] * x[4],
             ka * x[0] * x[1] - ki * x[3] * x[4] + (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb) * x[5],
             ki * x[4] * x[3] - x[5] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd),
             ki * x[4] * x[3] - x[6] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd + ktrm * x[3]) + (ktrm + kp) * x[3] * x[5],
             ki * x[4] * x[3] - x[7] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd + ktrm * x[3]) + (ktrm + kp) * x[3] * x[5] + 2 * x[6] * kp * x[3],
             x[5] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd + ktrm * x[3]),
             x[6] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd + ktrm * x[3]),
             x[7] * (ktrh * x[2] + ktrb + kd + ktrm * x[3])),
             new Options
             {
                 AbsoluteTolerance = 1e-6,
                 RelativeTolerance = 1e-6
             }).TakeWhile(p => p.T <= 7200).ToArray();
            foreach (var p in sol)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.X[0]);
            foreach (var p in sol) 
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.X[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print `p.X[0]` twice, not totally clear. But to get an array you can use Linq:

```
double[] values = sol.Select(p => p.X[0]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use it but it didn't work. where should I add these codes exactly?

Comment: Where you now those 2 foreach loops.